# Is it viable to use Hadoop with MongoDB as Database rather than HDFS

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hdfs

I am doing research in `Hadoop with MongoDB as Database` not HDFS. So, I need some guidance in terms of performance and usability.

**My scenario**

My data is

- Tweets from twitter
- Facebook News feed

I can get the data from twitter and Facebook API . In order for hadoop processing I need to store.

So my question is, Is it viable (or beneficial) to use Hadoop along with Mongo DB to store social networking data like twitter feeds, facebook posts, etc?  Or is it better to go with HDFS and store data in a file . Any expertise guidance will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is totally viable to do that. But it mainly depends on your needs. Basically on, **what do you want to do once you have the data?**

That said, MongoDB is definitely a good option. It is good at storing unstructured, deeply nested documents, like JSON in your case. You don't have to worry too much about nesting and relations in your data.  You don't have to worry about the schema as well. Schema-less storage is certainly a compelling reason to go with MongoDB.

On the other hand, I find HDFS more suitable for flat files, where you just have to pick the normalized data and start processing.

But these are just my thoughts. Others might have a different opinion. My final suggestion would be analyze your use case well and then finalize your store.

HTH

Comment: If there is huge document and want search from that document. It does line by line in HDFS. which takes too much time. Is there any option for fast search in BIG file?